# how use verb with but so

Tags: grammar

I came across the following sentence:
The clocks will be going back this weekend, but so are the temperatures.
My question is: why do we say ‘but so are the temperatures’ as if it is a question and not ‘but so the temperatures are’?  Is there a grammar rule here? I can’t remember.

Thanks

Comment: Note that there's a tense mismatch here. This could be corrected in a couple of ways. 1. The clocks are going back this weekend, but so are the temperatures. or 2.  The clocks will be going back this weekend, but so will the temperatures.

Comment: Consider it to be short for "also".

Answer (score 1):

The "but so" construction is one of [many](http://www.testmagic.com/Knowledge_Base/lists/grammar/inversion.htm) with inverted SV word order.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how it is used, *but so are* many others. One of the answers provides a very helpful link that lists a number of such constructs.